# Scikit-Learn Encoding Categorical Features - ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: regression, python, scikit-learn, numpy

I am trying to use sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder to binarize my categorical variables before use in some regression methods such as OLS, the Lasso etc.

I have a nested list like so:

```
l = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 2, 2], [0, 3, 2], [1, 4, 0], [0, 5, 2], [2, 2, 2], [0, 6, 2], [1, 7, 2], [0, 8, 3], [3, 4, 2], [0, 8, 4], [0, 9, 2], [1, 7, 1], [0, 10, 2], [0, 2, 5], [1, 11, 2], [1, 2, 3], [4, 12, 2], [1, 4, 2], [0, 13, 2], [0, 14, 2], [0, 15, 2], [0, 16, 0], [0, 17, 6], [5, 17, 2], [4, 17, 2], [0, 17, 3], [0, 2, 6], [0, 8, 6], [4, 2, 2], [4, 4, 2], [5, 15, 3], [0, 2, 3], [0, 7, 2], [1, 15, 2], [0, 17, 2], [0, 8, 2], [0, 2, 2], [4, 16, 2], [0, 1, 2], [5, 15, 2], [4, 8, 0], [0, 18, 3], [3, 11, 2], [6, 7, 2], [0, 8], [0, 19, 2], [1, 1, 2], [0, 7, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 4, 2], [0, 15, 3], [7, 8, 2], [1, 8, 0], [1, 16, 2], [0, 20, 2], [1, 8], [1, 8, 2], [0, 11, 1], [1, 21, 2], [4, 1, 2], [5, 1, 2], [2, 1, 2], [0, 22, 2], [8, 8, 2], [1, 8, 3], [1, 17, 2], [0, 8, 7], [0, 0, 2], [7, 7, 2], [2, 2, 8], [9, 8, 2], [5, 8, 2], [4, 8, 2], [0, 4, 3], [0, 23, 0], [0, 24, 2], [0, 2, 0], [3, 1, 2], [0, 25, 2], [0, 2, 9], [0, 11, 2], [1, 12, 2], [1, 26, 3], [0, 23, 2], [0, 27, 3], [3, 8, 2], [6, 8, 2], [6, 27, 2], [0, 16, 2], [0, 28, 2], [0, 29, 2], [0, 8, 0], [0, 8, 10], [0, 27, 2], [4, 7, 2], [0, 21, 2], [6, 11, 2], [0, 30, 2], [2, 8, 2], [0, 23, 3]]

from sklearn import preprocessing
enc = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()
enc.fit(l)
```

However, I am running into the error:

**`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`**

Here is the most telling callback as far as I can see:

```
    C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.pyc in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    458 
    459     """
--> 460     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    461 
    462 def asanyarray(a, dtype=None, order=None):
```

To try and solve this problem I have attempted to convert my list to a matrix and array in numpy but have had no luck.

In addition, I have made sure that each value in each of the nested lists is an integer. I have also tried converting them to floats, again with no success.

Any help would be wonderful. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to set `n_values='auto'` in your fit call?

Comment: It seems that the length of your sub-lists is not consistent.  For instance, l[46] contains only 2 values.  Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Thanks guys - I feel stupid for posting this now but after staring at this problem for hours I was at a loss. The problem was the l[46] sublist. I am suprised I didn't find this before but there you have it.

Comment: No problem...it happens to everyone!  You probably already figured this out, but it looks like l[57] is also only 2 values.

Comment: What @confuser says. In addition `np.unique(map(len, l))` gives you `[2, 3]`. `np.where(np.array(map(len, l)) == 2)` gives you the positions. After correcting this, it should work. If not, convert to numpy array.